# Shipping a new SQLite database in app update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

Our app will ship with a pre-populated database which continually downloads updates from our production server's database to stay up to date. When we make updates to our app's codebase and push those updates out to the AppStore we'll also include an updated db.sqlite file.

**My questions is**: when we do this I assume it will overwrite the users "old" database file that already exists?

I assume (and hope) the answer is yes, but just wanted to double check - I couldn't find any answers in Apple's documentation, but might have simply overlooked, or have been looking for the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "which continually downloads updates from our production server's database" I assume that means the app will download the data and update the database?  In which case the database must exist in the Documents folder and it won't get into the Documents folder until you copy it there.

Normally this is done by the app if the database file doesn't already exist, however if you want to overwrite the current database you'll need a mechanism to discover if the one in the Documents folder is out-of-date, compared to the one in the app bundle.  This probably means having a "metadata" table (with two columns `name`/`value`) containing a version number or some such.  You read both databases and decide whether or not to copy.

Comment: Yes, the database is copied to the Documents folder. So, just to confirm, we'll need to set some kind of flag, see if the current database is not the newest version, if so delete the database in the documents folder and copy the new database in its place?

Comment: @cjhill Well not a flag; you need a version number as this will occur time and again.  A simple incrementing integer number will suffice.

Comment: Sorry, by flag I meant just what you meant - a version number. My bad. Thanks for your help.